# Is this true: $(n \log n)^2 \in \Theta(\frac{n^3}{\log n})$

Tags: computational-complexity

I have to decide whether $(n \log n)^2 \in \Theta(\frac{n^3}{\log n})$ is true or false.

I can't really find a good approach, I'd assume it's wrong, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What’s the definition of $\Theta$?

Comment: Consider $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ where $f(n) = (n\log n)^2$ and  $g(n) = \frac{n^3}{\log n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $(n \log n)^2 \in \Theta(\frac{n^3}{\log n})$ there is a constant $C>0$ such that $$n^2\log^2n\ge \frac{Cn^3}{\log n}$$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  This simplifies to $$\log^3n\geq Cn$$ which is false.